# Python integerbox output

Tags: python

I've implemented an integerbox into my program. My question is:

Is it possible to change the output when somebody fills in a wrong value?

I can't find anything online about this. The code I used for the integerbox:

```
postcodeinvoer = easygui.integerbox(msg="Voer een postcode in:", title="Postcodezoeker",lowerbound=0,upperbound=999999)
```

Comment: what would a wrong value be?

Comment: A string, as it is an integerbox. It works, but want to change the standard output he gives when somebody fills in a wrong value.